# Getting the right order using ORDER with OFFSET and FETCH in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure that selects comments from a SQL Server database for a selected photo. I'm using the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` in order to select a numer of posts (10) on load and then to have a button that will prepend more posts to a DIV using AJAX.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_PhotoCmt]
    @IDphoto int,
    @IDuserInput nvarchar(150),
    @offset int,
    @fetch int = 10
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT 
       photoCmt.IDphotoCmt,
       photoCmt.photoCmt, 
       photoCmt.IDuser,
       photoCmt.photoCmtDate, //the date and time when the comment was added
       photoCmt.IDphoto,
   FROM 
       photoCmt 
   WHERE 
       photoCmt.IDphoto = @IDphoto 
   ORDER BY 
       photoCmt.photoCmtDate DESC 
   OFFSET @offset ROWS 
   FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY
```

Let's say there are 12 comments for a selected photo, I want the comments to be displayed on the page as follows (on first load):

Desired order

```
[Button PREPEND More]
Comment3
Comment4
Comment5
Comment6
Comment7
Comment8
Comment9
Comment10
Comment11
Comment12
```

Unfortunately the stored procedure is dispalying the comments as follows:

Undesired order

```
[Button PREPEND More]
Comment12
Comment11
Comment10
Comment9
Comment8
Comment7
Comment6
Comment5
Comment4
Comment3
```

How can I get my desired order? I tried many combinations but I can't get it right. I can't use `TOP` with `OFFSET` and `FETCH`.

Comment: erm, change the `DESC` to an `ASC`?

Comment: order is only for the date not for comments @jordel

Comment: add ASC instead of DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do OFFSET/FETCH first, then order the RESULT, something like:

```
select * from
(SELECT 
 photoCmt.IDphotoCmt,
 photoCmt.photoCmt, 
 photoCmt.IDuser,
 photoCmt.photoCmtDate, //the date and time when the comment was added
 photoCmt.IDphoto,
 FROM photoCmt
 WHERE photoCmt.IDphoto = @IDphoto 
 ORDER BY photoCmt.photoCmtDate DESC
 OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY)
order by photoCmtDate ASC
```

Comment: I think the outer order is different to the OP's requirement.

Comment: Are you sure? Well, I assume OP can adjust it if needed.

Comment: This solution works perfectly well for me. I'll also try @Jodrell solution below...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Essentially, use the descending order to get the page into a sub-query, then reorder the page in the outer query.

I would caveat my advice, using a different display order to page order could be very confusing to the user.

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1ed3/2)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_PhotoCmt]
        @IDphoto int,
        @IDuserInput nvarchar(150),
        @offset int,
        @fetch int = 10
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
                [O].[IDphotoCmt],
                [O].[photoCmt], 
                [O].[IDuser],
                [O].[photoCmtDate],
                [O].[IDphoto]
        FROM
                (SELECT 
                            [C].[IDphotoCmt],
                            [C].[photoCmt], 
                            [C].[IDuser],
                            [C].[photoCmtDate],
                            [C].[IDphoto]
                    FROM
                            [photoCmt] [C]
                    WHERE
                            [C].[IDphoto] = @IDphoto 
                    ORDER BY
                            [C].[photoCmtDate] DESC
                        OFFSET @offset ROWS
                        FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY) [O]
        ORDER BY
                   [O].[photoCmt] ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the `pagination` using `row_number()` and use `Order by` comment column to get the desired order. Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY photoCmt.photoCmtDate DESC) rn,
               photoCmt.IDphotoCmt,
               photoCmt.photoCmt,
               photoCmt.IDuser,
               photoCmt.photoCmtDate,--the date and time WHEN the comment was added
               photoCmt.IDphoto,
        FROM   photoCmt
        WHERE  photoCmt.IDphoto = @IDphoto) a
WHERE  rn BETWEEN @offset AND @offset + @fetch
ORDER  BY CONVERT(INT, Substring(photoCmt, Charindex('[0-9]', photoCmt), Len(photoCmt))) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any table variable and load data from query to table variable and then select that table variable as your order